# Continuously printing new data from database java

Tags: java

I'm working on a console based program where user can login and chat with other users. I want my program to continuously run the code and check for new messages. Every message has a unique id in the database. So if a message is already printed then it should skip that message and wait for the new ones. But my program is just printing the first message. I have also tried some other methods but in that case an infinite loop runs and it continuously print same messages again and again. Can anyone help me please? I'll be really thankful!

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Messages extends Login {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    boolean isLoggedin = login();
    String msg = "";
    int tempMsgID = 0;
    String senName = "";
    if(isLoggedin) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false", "root", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chat");
        while(rs.next()) {
            int dbRecID = rs.getInt("reciever_id");
            if(dbRecID == user_id) {
                while(true) {
                    msg = rs.getString("message");
                    int dbSenID = rs.getInt("sender_id");
                    int msgID = rs.getInt("message_id");
                    if(tempMsgID == msgID) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
                        while(rs1.next()) {
                            int senID = rs1.getInt("id");
                            if(senID == dbSenID) {
                                senName = rs1.getString("name");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(senName+" sent you a message: "+msg);
                    }
                    tempMsgID = msgID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First of all I would suggest to change your first query to something like `SELECT * FROM chat WHERE reciever_id = user_id` (where user_id is that variable you compare dbRecID with). Then whenever your print a message, flag it (create a new field perhaps called `Printed` and update the table when you print it). Then you query only the ones not flagged.

Comment: The variable `reciever_id` isn't defined anywhere.  Did you intend that to be a part of your query?

Comment: Iterating over the database rows on the client site (in Java) is going to bring the system to its knees very quickly. I advise you learn more about how to use SQL, for example, using WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: It's only half-implemented, I'd say. You are talking about "new" messages, yet there is no notion of "new" message in your program. It's also not a brilliant idea to do a silent `System.exit(0)` on some condition. Ultimately, just debug the damn thing and see for yourself.